# How to implement Voice Activity Detection in Java?

Tags: java, listener, microphone, javasound, voice-recognition

I need to implement a voice activity detection algorithm in Java so that I can know when to start and/or stop recording audio. I am looking for an algorithm that can take either a byte[], a target-data-line, or an audio file as input. Also, a solution would preferably not use external dependencies.

Comment: Voice Activity Detection is VERY different from detecting silence. I do not want background noise to be detected preferably.

Comment: While the the question states 'detect silence', the method I showed detects sound above/below any set limit.  If the BG noise is anywhere beyond 'low', the sound would be hard to hear.  If it is low, then the technique I outlined will detect it, with the appropriate limit.  Noticing also that you have asked a question about pitch shifting.. Detecting sound levels is an order of magnitude easier than pitch shifting.  If you cannot sort this, you've got a snowball's chance in hell of achieving that.

Comment: I already have implemented that code. I want information on pitch shifting or any other algorithms that will further improve my code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Give a look at [TarsosDSP](https://github.com/JorenSix/TarsosDSP) as source of inspiration: It is so far the best open source Java library to deal with Audio Detection. It is purely written in Java and briefly provides:

*SoundDetection

PitchDetection

PercussionDetection

Audio Time Stretching

Pitch Shifting

IIR-filters*

Check also the official [paper](http://0110.be/files/attachments/415/2013.08.20.tarsos_jnmr_author_version.pdf) and [manual](http://0110.be/releases/TarsosDSP/TarsosDSP-latest/TarsosDSP-latest-Manual.pdf) for a better grasp on the topic.

Comment: Actually implemented this on my own using TarosDSP as guidance and never got around to updating the answer, but hey you deserve the accepted answer just for digging this up.